# Can I access a file in the intermediate layer of docker image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have dockerfile like below. I add some files to build application then remove them. I push it to an Amazon ECR repository. Can someone access the removed files in the intermediate layer?

```
FROM X
...
ADD Y Z
...
RUN rm Z
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes

Good question, I tested using:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:latest
ADD secretfile.txt ./secretfile.txt
RUN rm ./secretfile.txt
```

The intermediate container is named `ded0652b1b4b`

```
Step 2/3 : ADD secretfile.txt ./secretfile.txt
---> Using cache
---> ded0652b1b4b
```

Doing an `docker inspect ded0652b1b4b` shows (partial output):

```
 "Id": "sha256:a3f069abb5b5d712ec2977e185667e67083360fad3b82fbf2994cb25f137fcb3",
 "Cmd": [
   "/bin/sh",
   "-c",
   "#(nop) ADD file:5d17740f2cfb728d9d94605430e551fddc46fda9f68caa9a3b51eabb126db393 in ./secretfile.txt " ]
```

Then building a container in interactive mode using that image id:

```
docker run it "a3f069abb5b5d712ec2977e185667e67083360fad3b82fbf2994cb25f137fcb3"
ls
...           run             secretfile.txt  sys             usr
```

You can see `secretfile.txt` is found in the image. (And of course it is not found in the container built from the full image from the dockerfile)