# Can I access a file in the intermediate layer of docker image by inspecting?

Tags: docker, security

After reading [Can I access a file in the intermediate layer of docker image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58599395/can-i-access-a-file-in-the-intermediate-layer-of-docker-image) I learned that if the id of intermediate layer is known, files to be deleted in further layer are not concealed. This is what told "Don’t do this!" in [Don’t leak your Docker image’s build secrets](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/docker-build-secrets/).

But in the above links it looks like the threat only exists if a build log leaks and thanks to buildkit intermediate layer id is no longer revealed, so I understand that there's no threat in build phase. Then, is it possible to retrieve layer id from published image by user, by `docker inspect` for example?

#### Added

Apologies not to being clarified, I'm talking about layer id which is able to be specified in `docker run -it <layer_id>` . My concern is a possibility of running container on certain layer and leakage of files' content.

As mentioned in [Can I access a file in the intermediate layer of docker image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58599395/can-i-access-a-file-in-the-intermediate-layer-of-docker-image) when building image without BuildKit intermediate layer id is revealed, can be specified in `docker run -it` so the files are all accessible. But layer ids retrieved by `docker inspect` cannot be specified; it results "Error response from daemon: No such image".

#### Added

More specifically. You build image by this Dockerfile then can you read the content of `.env` ?

```
FROM alpine:latest
ADD .env /.env
RUN rm /.env
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update:

If X has access to your image, then all files from your final image can be accessed by X using:

```
FROM <image_name>
COPY --from=./ /tmp
```

If X has access to your image, and wanted to access a file thats not present in the final image, but rather only in intermediate layer, then X will need to know the ID of the intermediate layer.

The ID can be determine using `docker image inspect <image_name>`. Or you can use the Image ID exposed by `dive` for each intermediate layer.

You are correct that seeing the file contents is not yet supported by `dive`, but there is a feature request for this already: https://github.com/wagoodman/dive/issues/336

### Original Answer

You can do this using `dive` utility, even if you don't know the id of the intermediate layers.

> dive
>
> A tool for exploring a docker image, layer contents, and discovering ways to shrink the size of your Docker/OCI image.
> https://github.com/wagoodman/dive

[image: dive]

Installation instructions: https://github.com/wagoodman/dive#installation

You can build your image as usual, and then you can run:

```
$ dive <image_name>
```

and then you can *dive* into each intermediate layers, and see the directory structure.

Comment: Apologies, my question was not clarified. I hope you check the added part and I can get another reply. I already checked `dive` and seems like I can neither transfer file to host machine nor look content on `dive`, so it's not a problem for me.

Comment: Thanks to your hint, I learnt that files in image can be easily leaked by `docker save` so having sensitive data in it is every time vulnerable. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> Then, is it possible to retrieve layer id from published image by user, by docker inspect for example?

Yes. You can, for example, show all layer IDs with `docker inspect <image name> -f '{{.RootFS.Layers}}'`.

> Thanks to buildkit intermediate layer id is no longer revealed

It's not that the intermediate layer ID is no longer revealed. The layer ID must be revealed for Docker's layer caching to work. The reason why BuildKit is more secure is that it gives you options for using secrets besides copying the secrets into the image. If you don't use those options, then BuildKit is no more secure than the previous system.

Comment: Apologies, my question was not clarified. I hope you check the added part and I can get another reply.